# Deploy R app in shinyapps.io- Error:parsing manifest

Tags: r, shiny

I want to simply publish my app in shinyapps.io website. When I run deployApp() I got this message:

Error: Unhandled Exception: Child Task 32916512 failed: Error parsing manifest: Unsupported locale: 4409_4409.UTF-8
    Execution halted

```
Preparing to deploy application...DONE
Uploading application bundle...DONE
Deploying application: 42336...
Waiting for task: 32916511
  error: Parsing manifest
################################## Begin Log ################################## 
################################### End Log ################################### 
Error: Unhandled Exception: Child Task 32916512 failed: Error parsing manifest: Unsupported locale: 4409_4409.UTF-8
Execution halted
```

- I read data from TXT file
- I already tried with R version 3.1.1, 3.1.3, 3.0.2 But still the error is there.
- EDIT: I just found out, the error appears even when I publish blank server.R with a simple ui.R

Here some codes , server.R

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
shinyServer(function(input,output){
  output$graph <- renderPlot({
    if(input$radiobutton=="Tools"){
      x <- as.matrix(allSkillsNum3[-1]) 
      rownames(x) <- allSkillsNum3[, 1]   
      p=barplot(t(x),horiz=TRUE,legend.text = T,col=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8))          
    }
    else{   
      x <- as.matrix(allSkillsNum3[-1])
      rownames(x) <- allSkillsNum3[, 1]   
      p=barplot(t(x)...

    }
    print(p) }) })
```

Comment: I don't know for sure, but it looks like an encoding problem, especially since you are reading from a txt.

Comment: I also tried with excel file, but it does not work on my system. The same code was run on the lecturer's system.(for me it just works offline)

Comment: R doesn't do too well with excel files; have you tried a csv?

Comment: Since it works offline, I thought it'd be fine in shinyapps.io website. I'll try csv now and will tell the results.

Comment: I've tried, but it didn't work .

Comment: at this point you might want to ask the developers on their google group, https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/shinyapps-users

Comment: I asked, waiting for response. Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 2):

It is solved , Thanks to Andy Kipp in shinyapps.io googlegroups.... I'll put the solution here for other programmers

It was because my system locale in Control Panel was set to English(Malaysia).
So I chose English(United States)

Control Panel> Clock, Language and Region > Change Location > Administrative Tab > Change System Locale

Now, when I run the code:

```
> shinyapps:::systemLocale()
Detecting system locale ... en_US
[1] "en_US"
```

Next step is deploying app ... These are the steps :

```
options(shinyapps.locale.cache = FALSE)

then run:

shinyapps:::detectLocale()

Then re-deploy:

deployApp(...)
```

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

Deleting manifest.json from local folder also helps. This solves the problem.