# Deploy R app in shinyapps.io - "Error:parsing manifest: Manifest file manifest.json checksum mismatch"

Tags: r, shiny, manifest.json

everyone!

I am having problems deploying my Shiny App. When deploying the app, I get the following console output:

```
Preparing to deploy application...DONE
Uploading bundle for application: 177552...DONE
Deploying bundle: 813581 for application: 177552 ...
Waiting for task: 383835116
  building: Parsing manifest
################################ Begin Task Log ################################ 
################################# End Task Log ################################# 
Error: Unhandled Exception: Child Task 383835121 failed: Error parsing manifest: Manifest file manifest.json checksum mismatch
Execution halted
```

Please take into account the following facts:

- I've already checked this solution, and it didn't work:
  [Deploy R app in shinyapps.io- Error:parsing manifest [SOLVED]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30181804/deploy-r-app-in-shinyapps-io-errorparsing-manifest-solved)
- Also, I've had saved a previous working version of the app, downloaded it back via the "download bundle" option of ShainyApps, and I get the same message.

What can I do in order to solve this? Thanks a lot! Don't hesitate to ask me for further details if necessary.

Comment: Have you tried updating Shiny, R and RStudio?

Comment: I've updated thrice of them, and still the same message. Dunno what it can be. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's not a solution, but it's a way of preventing the error. The "trigger" of the error is the fact that I was working on the Shiny bundle obtained using "download bundle" option of ShinyApps. It's possible it has to do with the encoding or the MD5 checksum, but NEVER work on files from the bundle. I can state the aforementioned as I had a copy on GitHub, cloned it, worked on it, deployed the new version, and it worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Adding to Elias's answer. When you download a Shiny bundle, there is a file included called "manifest.json". Checksum error here.

Delete "manifest.json" and deploy app again.